# Paralist with alwaysadjust

Tags: formatting, lists, itemize, paralist

I want to align elements in an itemization list such that no item label uses part of the page margin. I am using the paralist package for this. However, the item indentation is not right in all cases:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pxfonts}
\usepackage{paralist}
%\usepackage[alwaysadjust]{paralist}

\begin{document}
\noindent

\section{Complexity classes}

Please note that the following list of complexity classes is not 
only important, but also contains no information about them.

\begin{itemize}
\item[\textbf{PTIME}:] A complexity class
\item[\textbf{NP}:] Yet another complexity class
\item[\textbf{PSPACE}:] Guess what...
\end{itemize}

\section{Questions}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Where are the other complexity classes?
  \item Perhaps this document does not need them?
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: How things look like now but should not]

The problem seems to be that there is a minimum label width for which the *NP* label is smaller. Without the *pxfonts* package, the problem would not occur. Now one could use the "*alwaysadjust*" option to paralist, but then the file does not compile anymore. Using the "*olditem*" option to paralist would make the list labels extend into the page margin.

So how to I align the *NP* element properly?

Comment: Why don't you use a description list for the first list - this works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `description` list instead works, and also saves you having to explicitly make the label bold:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pxfonts}
\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}
\noindent

\section{Complexity classes}

Please note that the following list of complexity classes is not 
only important, but also contains no information about them.

\begin{description}
\item[PTIME:] A complexity class
\item[NP:] Yet another complexity class
\item[PSPACE:] Guess what...
\end{description}

\section{Questions}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Where are the other complexity classes?
  \item Perhaps this document does not need them?
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the `itemize` environment with the `compactdesc` environment from the `paralist` package.
This produces
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pxfonts}
\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}
\noindent

\section{Complexity classes}

Please note that the following list of complexity classes is not 
only important, but also contains no information about them.

\begin{compactdesc}
\item[PTIME:] A complexity class
\item[\textbf{NP}:] Yet another complexity class
\item[\textbf{PSPACE}:] Guess what...
\end{compactdesc}

\section{Questions}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Where are the other complexity classes?
  \item Perhaps this document does not need them?
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```